# dialing the phone number when swipe on the phone icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to dial a phone number if the user swipes on the phone icon in react Native. For e.g. if I have (999)-996-5432 on my phone then when user swipes the icon then this number should be automatically dialed. Below is my code for handleclick

```
export default class ServiceListDetails extends Component {
  handleClick = (link) => {
    Linking.canOpenURL(link).then(suppported => {
        if (supported) {
            Linking.openURL(link);
        } else {
            console.log('Don\'t know how to open URI: ' + link);
        }
    });
};
```

Below is the code where I am calling the handleClick from:

```
 return(






                        <Text  style={styles.Address1}>{item.addr} </Text>
                        <View style={styles.phoneImg}>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                  onPress={() => { this.handleClick('tel:${item.phone}')}}>
                                      <Image source={require('../images/Phone.png')} style={styles.actionImage}/>
                             </TouchableOpacity>
                            <Text style={styles.Address1}>{item.phone}</Text>
                        </View>
)
```

item.phone is coming from my JSON file. Below is my JSON file:

```
[
{

        "id":"2",
        "fk": 1,
        "addr": "123 test drive, Ring road test",
        "phone": "(999)-345-7896"
},

{
        "id":"3",
        "fk": 1,
        "addr": "123 test drive, Test Road",
        "phone": "(951)-765-2222"


}
]
```

I already deployed the application on iPhone and tried to swipe the phone number and it is not doing anything. I know phone icon swiping wont work in emulator.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo error (suppported & supported). fix this and it will work

```
Linking.canOpenURL(link).then(suppported => {
    if (supported) {
```

Comment: Thank You. I dont know how I missed it. Thank you again